# Apache .png Forbidden

Tags: apache

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.25 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Server MPM: prefork
Server Built: Mar 20 2017 15:23:03
```

Not Working

```
http://example.com/images/highlightsicon.png
```

Working same .png difrent name

```
 http://example.com/images/highligsicon.png
```

same permission i just rename it

On apache logs i got this

```
 [client 179.43.176.2:14178] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/username/public_html/example.com/images/highlightsicon.png
```

This happen today yeastarday evrething works perfect today i can't open this .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#<FilesMatch "(.ht[access|passwd]|.user.ini|php.ini)">
# Require all denied
#</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "(.htaccess|.passwd|.user.ini|php.ini)">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

from cpanel [forum](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/apache-forbidden.596483/)